# Web Services not executing properly on Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat7, restful-url

I am trying to create a `Web Service` that converts temperature from `C` to `F`. I followed a basic tutorial that is :
http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/
I have followed the same steps that the post suggests and I am running the project using `apache Tomcat v7`. However, the output does not show up the way the tutorial says it should. When I run my project I get an error that says `HTTP Status 404 - /RestJerseyExample/ ; The resource is not available`. I am new to this and I don't understand where I may be going wrong. I am working on `Windows 7`. Suggestions much appreciated!

here is my `web.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/crunchify/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

also, here is my `pom.xml` :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>RESTJerseyExample</groupId>
<artifactId>RESTJerseyExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please provide configuration and resource files like web.xml

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: Are you trying to reach your server via "/RestJerseyExample/" context? I think it should be "/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/crunchify/{your_resource_context}"

Comment: The tutorial mentions the 1st. My class name however, is the 2nd one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't register your resources. You should add in your `<servlet></servlet>` configuration in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.crunchify.restjersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And try this following URL:
`http://localhost:8080/crunchify/`

Comment: just tried what you suggested, I still am getting Error 404

Comment: what resource are you trying to reach ?